# memory leak vc++ and mysql (my_thr_init.c)

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in my VC++ program (built with MS VS2008). It’s a small test app connecting to MySql DB server (mysql ver 5.5.25a-log) . The app is using mysql c connector ver.  6.0.2. (linking with ‘mysqlclient.lib’),it’s  works just find but has a memory leak of 124 bytes. Visual leak detector’s call stack traces it to ‘my_thr_init.c’ file.
My code:

```
MYSQL realData;
MYSQL *myData=NULL;

//this is done in InitInstance
    myData = mysql_init(&realData);
    if ( mysql_real_connect( myData, ip_addr, user, pwd, NULL,0,NULL,0))
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Connected!"));
    }
    else {
        AfxMessageBox(mysql_error(myData));
    }

//and this is done in ExitInctance
    if(myData!=NULL)  {
        TRACE("ExitInstance  - closing myData\n");
        mysql_close( myData );
        mysql_library_end();
        myData=NULL;
    }
```

When app closes this is from the output window:

```
    ...
ExitInstance  - closing myData
    Detected memory leaks!
    Dumping objects ->
    {2720} normal block at 0x05AAB830, 124 bytes long.
     Data: <        0;+     > 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 3B 2B 01 FF FF FF FF 
    Object dump complete.
    The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x98c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x828) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x424) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xb6c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xdcc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
    ---------- Block 2711 at 0x05AAB830: 124 bytes ----------
      Call Stack:
        g:\bs\connector-c-vs2008-32bit\src\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\mysys\my_thr_init.c (330): HCCAdmin.exe!my_thread_init + 0x9 bytes
        f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\thrdcore.cpp (109): HCCAdmin.exe!_AfxThreadEntry + 0xF bytes
        f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c (348): HCCAdmin.exe!_callthreadstartex + 0xF bytes
        f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c (331): HCCAdmin.exe!_threadstartex
        0x74AD33AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
        0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
        0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
      Data:
        02 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    30 3B 2B 01    FF FF FF FF     ........ 0;+.....
        00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
        00 00 00 00    DC 01 00 00    E4 01 00 00    F0 01 00 00     ........ ........
        F8 3A 2B 01    FF FF FF FF    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     .:+..... ........
        00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
        34 0C 00 00    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     4....... ........
        01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
        00 00 00 00    3C F7 4A 06    00 00 00 00                    ....<.J. ........


    Visual Leak Detector detected 1 memory leak (10178 bytes).
    Largest number used: 219192 bytes.
    Total allocations: 2113741 bytes.
    Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional, see the [MySQL C Api Reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-function-overview.html):

> The purpose of calling mysql_library_init() and mysql_library_end() is to provide proper initialization and finalization of the MySQL library. For applications that are linked with the client library, they provide improved memory management. If you don't call mysql_library_end(), a block of memory remains allocated. (This does not increase the amount of memory used by the application, but some memory leak detectors will complain about it.) For applications that are linked with the embedded server, these calls start and stop the server.

The `mysql_library_end` should correctly release the memory used, whilst initially showing as a "leak". There are [numerous](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11014) [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7619) submissions on bugs.mysql.com about this too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did found Philip's answer in that other thread and it helped me to use 'mysql_library_end()' function call in my code. Without it memory leaks are much bigger. So to summarize, the memory leak is intentional. Can’t say it’s not strange but ok, thanks once more.

Comment: @user2050867 Not a problem, from some of the bugs I went through in looking this up, supposedly it's something to do with character set caching to speed up any future calls to init. That was in 2006, though, there's a high chance that even *more* is persistently cached now.